# NetBeans C/C++ does not build with GCC and gives message "Unable to create process - no HostInfo available"

Tags: gcc, netbeans, compilation

I have versions 8.1 and 8.2 of NetBeans upon a Windows 10 PC. 8.1 will compile and run C/C++ programs perfectly but 8.2 will not and simply gives the really helpful message:

`Unable to create process - no HostInfo available`

The odd thing is that both versions of NetBeans are set to use the same versions of the GCC compiler and tools. Version 8.1 displays the following:

[image]

While 8.2 displays:

[image]

Can anyone suggest why this is?

I have tried uninstalling the C++ plugin in NetBeans 8.2 and reinstalling it but all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved by changing environment settings to include new variables for TOOLS_PATH and UTILITIES_PATH in the Windows PATH. Both variables are set to C:\Cygwin64\bin.